# List of values vs radio button group vs drop-down list

Tags: forms, selection, choices

In the thread on [GUI Design - ComboBoxes Versus Lists or RadioButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993348/gui-design-comboboxes-versus-lists-or-radiobuttons) and [Dropdown vs radio button](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/dropdown-vs-radio-button), I've read about comboboxes vs. radio button groups. In our legacy application, we also use lookup lists a lot:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffOZgq.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

It is a button next to a textfield, which launches a popup where the user can search for some value and select it. When is this kind of choice-selection  appropriate? We use it quite a lot and I don't know if we should. It is sometimes used, even for only four choices?

Answer (score 2):

There are some good implementations of a [select list being expressed as a drop-down menu with type-ahead filtering](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) available now, which accomplishes the same thing without imposing a pop-up.

The pop-up has the additional cognitive load of "how do I get rid of this?" (answered as "use the `[select]` or `[cancel]` buttons), as well as the additional effort load of actually doing so. With type-ahead-drop-down you simply select the value, while here you click a button, click an option, click a button.

---

<sup>I also suspect there's also a possibility of [disrupting the user's short term memory](http://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/mental-mishaps/201205/doorways-cause-forgetting), what with the imposed context switch. See 
[*Walking through doorways causes forgetting: Situation models and experienced space. Radvansky, Copeland; 2006*](http://link.springer.com/article/10.3758%2FBF03193261)
and [*Walking through doorways causes forgetting: Further explorations. Radvansky, Krawietza, Tamplina; 2011*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/17470218.2011.571267). I'd really like to see some UX research done on whether the same effect occurs with pop-ups/lightboxes/etc.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think it is OK, even for short lists:

- It promotes consistency: no surprise when you click on the button, you will always get the same. It develops automatisms of usage, without having to aim for a component that can vary depending on the content of the list.
- Short lists are OK, and even better: you can see at a glance all elements. The search field is then a bit redundant, but nobody forces the user to use it.
- It is non-obtrusive, popping out when needed, going away after usage.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think this is a less good alternative. The only thing is that it is used along with radio button groups and comboboxes, there is not a guideline for it now. What is better used in some cases? In one form, we have now a combination of radio buttons, comboboxes and this alternative. Is it just enough to choose one or can we set some kind of guidelines?

Comment: Your component is a good substitute to combo boxes: scrolling might be easier, the find field is good for lot of entries. Radio buttons get an advantage: when there are few choices (say up to 5), they allow to see at a glance what are the alternatives.

Comment: I would thus keep only radio buttons for the reason above, and your component, and make a rule / guideline to indicate when to use one instead of the other.