# When to use a group of radio buttons and when to use a select drop down

Tags: forms, web-app, input, selection, wizard

I have a step in a wizard scenario.

The user has a choice of 3 options before they can tap 'Next'.

For those 3 options **do I use a select drop down list or a group of 3 radio buttons**?

Comment: Please see http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/10728/dropdown-vs-radio-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say for three options use radio buttons.

All options are clearly on the screen when the form loads and you only have one click to choose.

For more complicated lists, perhaps those that are split up by category, I would use a drop-down to avoid overwhelming the user with form elements

Comment: When possible, allow the user to see all the options up front, rather than having them click on something to display all the options.

Comment: I would limit radio buttons to 4 possibly 5, anything above that move to a drop down list.